# Optimization - Lagrange multipliers : minimum cost/maximum production

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Business operates on the basis of the production function $Q=25\cdot K^{1/3}\cdot L^{2/3}$ (where $L$ = units of work and $K$ = units of capital).

If the prices of inputs $K$ and $L$ are respectively $3$ euros and $6$ euros per unit, then find :

a) the optimal combination of inputs that the company must occupy to minimize its costs, producing $Q = 600$ production units. What is the minimum production cost?

b) the optimal combination of inputs that the company must occupy to maximize production, if the amount of money available for the purchase of inputs is $450$ euros. What is the maximum possible level of production?

$$$$

I have done the following:

a) We consider the function $f(K,L)=600\cdot 25\cdot K^{1/3}\cdot L^{2/3}$. Do we apply now Lagrange multipliers?

b) We consider the cost function $C(K,L)=K+L$. Do we apply now Lagrange multipliers? But for which function?

Comment: Shouldn't we apply the Lagrange multiplier for the cost function as $ C(K,L) = 3K + 6L $ ?

Comment: Is the answer to the first question 120 euros ?

Comment: For the first question: $600 = 25 \cdot K^{1/3} \cdot L^{2/3} \implies g(K, L) = K L^2 - 24^3 = 0$ is the constraint. The optimization function is $f(K, L) = 3 K + 6L$

Comment: Does the answer help, Mary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You minimize the cost function. The cost function is $3K+6L$, since the prices  are respectively $3$ euros and $6$. Then the output is $600$. Now you set this value equal to the output function to obtain the constraint.

$$25\cdot K^{1/3}\cdot L^{2/3}=600 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 600-25\cdot K^{1/3}\cdot L^{2/3}=0$$

Indeed you now apply the method of Lagrange multipliers. the Lagrangian function is

$$\mathcal L=3K+6L+\lambda\left(600-25\cdot K^{1/3}\cdot L^{2/3}\right)$$

I think you can proceed. Give a reply if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Comment: You're welcome.